# ASP.NET (classic): Autoregister Httpmodule that handles all requests (including unmanaged)

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I've created a custom HttpModule and I'm trying to make sure it gets automatically registered (so that the users don't have to resort to the \<<modules> element). In order to do that, I've started by adding the `PreApplicationStartMethod` to the assembly that contains the module:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AutoRegisterHttpModule), nameof(AutoRegisterHttpModule.Start))]
```

And then, I've register the module with the following code:

```
public static class AutoRegisterHttpModule {
    public static void Start() {
        HttpApplication.RegisterModule(typeof(GrmMagickModule));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I've noticed that this does not produce the same result as using the <add> element:

```
<modules>
 <add type="Grm.Magick.Resizing.GrmMagickModule, Grm.Magick.Resizing" name="GrmMagick"/>
</modules>
```

When I do this, my module will handle all requests. However, that doesn't happen when I register my module automatically. In these cases, I need to change the modules declaration so that it looks like this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

Any chance of getting the same results with auto registration?

Thanks.

Comment: Well if you think about it (and correct me if I'm wrong here anyone), the asp.net application code will only run for managed requests, so it seems logical that in that situation the module would not run if the main asp.net application code is not also being executed. I _think_ the difference here is that you're making the module part of the app itself, not part of the IIS pipeline. But I'm not 100% sure if that's the exact reason (hence comment, not answer)

Comment: hum...not sure about that...after all, iis is being used in integrated mode (where there's only one pipeline...)

Comment: Like I said I don't know enough to be certain, but for me the clue comes with the fact you had to add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to get the code-based version to work. To me that indicates that the module was only running for managed requests (served by the application) until you explicitly ordered that managed code modules be used for all requests. Presumably that injects the modules in all circumstances, not just those which are served by managed code

Comment: P s. Yes there's only one pipeline, but the whole point of a pipe is you can intercept the request and serve it at different points in the pipe. So presumably non managed requests are served by a different bit. When I have some time I might go and dig into this a bit more, it's probably useful to understand it a bit better

Comment: But it's a really strange behavior, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Yes...and no. Some things might only make sense to run in the managed context, so it's good to have ways to limit them to that, but equally yes it might be useful to have a way to auto register something to run in all contexts. I don't know, clearly I can't speak for the designers and what the logic of the original concept was

Comment: No, I meant it's strange to have different results (I expected to have the some results with auto and default usage of <add> element). And running all the requests through the managed pipeline is not so great (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/oct/25/caveats-with-the-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-in-iis-78), so I'll remove auto-registration feature...

Comment: Just to add more feedback (based on answer from @rick-strahl). Registration through web.config is an "iis feature", while dynamic registration through code is an asp.net feature...since the precondition attribute is part of IIS, then it seems like it's not possible to configure that when registering modules through the pre application startup method (though it could be possible by writing directly to the web.config file or using IIS management tooling - haven't tested it though)

Comment: Yes that was pretty much my original theory. By the way which answer are you referring to? I don't see any other answers here

Comment: I've pinged Rick and was lucky enough to get an answer...